# JSON data sorting with custom logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I have a following data JSON data which I have to group by priority then organise the grouped data in order where first two result will be type 1 and next 1 of type 2 and next 1 will be type 3 and then repeat

```
{
    "list": [{
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf05",
            "type": 1,
            "priority": 1,
            "name": "John"
        },
        {
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf07",
            "type": 2,
            "priority": 1,
            "name": "Jack"
        },
        {
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf09",
            "type": 1,
            "priority": 1,
            "name": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf09",
            "type": 2,
            "priority": 1,
            "name": "Kiles"
        },
        {
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf11",
            "type": 1,
            "priority": 1,
            "name": "Stacy"
        },
        {
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf13",
            "type": 1,
            "priority": 2,
            "name": "Stacy"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to do this by using lodash

```
_.chain(myArray).groupBy("priority").map(item=> _.groupBy(item,"offerType")).value()
```

This give me grouped and sorted result accordingly but now I am stuck with custom ordering in the results. How to achieve the desired order in list.

The result I am looking for

```
 {
    "list": [{
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf05",
            "type": 1,
            "priority": 1,
            "name": "John"
        },
        {
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf09",
            "type": 1,
            "priority": 1,
            "name": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf07",
            "type": 2,
            "priority": 1,
            "name": "Jack"
        },
        {
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf11",
            "type": 1,
            "priority": 1,
            "name": "Stacy"
        },
        {
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf09",
            "type": 2,
            "priority": 1,
            "name": "Kiles"
        },
        {
            "_id": "555ed01e0f398a7b1436bf13",
            "type": 2,
            "priority": 2,
            "name": "Stacy"
        }
    ]
   }
```

Comment: It is not JSON.

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: as George said, it is not JSON, and also, the objects inside the array you posted here, are all with errors, missing `,` ,`:` and a invalid type value in the last one.

Comment: @CalvinNunes   sorry for that I corrected the JSON

Comment: @str thanks ! I added that in hurry which I have corrected

Comment: @GeorgeJempty thanks I corrected that

Comment: @BipinChandraTripathi I don't understand the logic in which way you want to order the array. Is by priority or by type or both of them? Doesn't look like is ordered to me your desired outcome.

Comment: @NickHTTPS I just want to reorder the objects in array with criteria which is first group them with priority so that same priority are in one group then sort them within group in such a way that first two items are of type 1 and next one of type 2 and repeat within the group and same for the other groups and finally the returned result as array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the result it seems to me that you just want to sort, not group, your data:

```
result = _.chain(myArray).sortBy("priority", "type")
```

Comment: I want to sort within the group and sorting will be first two result will be type 1 and next 1 will be type 2 and then repeat within the group

Comment: the result data you show does not have groups, it is just sorted.  is the result data right?